# Error : E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc

Tags: android

When I try to run my application she crashes and give me this error:

```
E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
```

I have a huawei p8 and I have already searched about a solution, but nothing works can you explain me this error and perhaps gives me a solution?

Comment: Looks like something related to the memory allocation.  HAL typically stands for hardware abstraction layer, and the gralloc items ... I believe these are memory allocation specific messages.  Would need to know more about the app and crash/stacktraces.

Comment: @BonanzaDriver It is when I try to open a fragment, I don't know why but it crashes. I just avec a w/art : failed execv and W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/woowin.woowin-2/lib/arm64 nothing else

Comment: I have the same problem with my Huawei P8. I made a custom theme, added it in the manifest, but the app crashes at launch. Same error message.